# 'GoogleApiException: Parameter "spreadsheetId" is missing' exception trying to access Google Sheets API

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to access Google Sheets API on Unity with this script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

using System.Text;
using TMPro;
public class GoogleSheetsTest : MonoBehaviour
{

 public TextMeshProUGUI text;

 string p12PathFromAsset;

 
 const string sheetNameAndRange = "A!A1:D13";
 const string serviceAccountEmail = "MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT";
 static SheetsService service;

 private void Awake()
 {
     RequestPath();
 }

 void RequestPath()
 {
     string keyPath = "P12_KEY_LOCATION";
     string realPath;

     if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
     {
         // Android
         string oriPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, keyPath);

         // Android only use WWW to read file
         WWW reader = new WWW(oriPath);
         while (!reader.isDone) { }

         realPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "P12_KEY_STUFF";
         System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(realPath, reader.bytes);

         Debug.Log("Running Android");

         p12PathFromAsset = realPath.Replace("p12",".p12");
     }
     else
     {
         // iOS
         p12PathFromAsset = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, keyPath);
     }

     SyncData();

 }

 void SyncData()
 {

     var certificate = new X509Certificate2(p12PathFromAsset, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

     text.text = p12PathFromAsset;

     ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = new[] { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets }
            /*
             Without this scope, it will :
             GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
             Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 
             2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication 
             credential.
             lol..
             */
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));

     service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
     {
         HttpClientInitializer = credential,
     });

     string spreadsheetid = "MY_SPREADSHEET_ID";
     var request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetid, sheetNameAndRange);

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     ValueRange response = request.Execute();
     IList<IList<object>> values = response.Values;
     if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
     {
         foreach (IList<object> row in values)
         {
             foreach (object cell in row)
             {
                 sb.Append(cell.ToString() + " ");
             }

             //Concat the whole row
             Debug.Log(sb.ToString());
             text.text = sb.ToString();

             sb.Clear();
         }
     }
     else
     {
         Debug.Log("No data found.");
     }
 }
```

Its a relatively simple script that gets the google Sheet with the spreadsheetId: MY_SPREADSHEET_ID, and authorises the access with a Google service account using a p12 key. "A!A1:D13" is the rows and columns of the spreadsheet it looks for.

This works fine on Unity Editor.It manages to get the p12 key location on android and auth the access, but it gives this exception and can't retrieve the spreadsheet data:

> 2020.10.09 16:42:06.910 6047 6067 Error Unity GoogleApiException: Parameter "spreadsheetId" is missing

> 2020.10.09 16:42:06.910 6047 6067 Error Unity   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1[TResponse].AddParameters (Google.Apis.Requests.RequestBuilder requestBuilder, Google.Apis.Requests.Parameters.ParameterCollection inputParameters) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

> 2020.10.09 16:42:06.910 6047 6067 Error Unity   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1[TResponse].CreateBuilder () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0  2020.10.09 16:42:06.910 6047 6067 Error Unity   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1[TResponse].CreateRequest (System.Nullable`1[T] overrideGZipEnabled) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0  2020.10.09 16:42:06.910 6047 6067 Error Unity   at DG.Tweening.TweenCallback`1[T].EndInvoke (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

> 2020.10.09 16:42:06.910 6047 6067 Error Unity   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.SetValue[T] (System.String name, T value, System.Func`2[T,TResult] toStringConverter) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

> 2020.10.09 16:42:06.910 6047 6067 Error Unity   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1[TResponse].ExecuteUnparsedAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken ca

I have tried a const string variable for the spreadsheetid, getting rid of the variable and just typing the string on the method, but i don't think the problem is with the id since the script works perfectly on UnityEditor.

I'm at a total loss at this and i appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Google Sheets is not officially supported for Unity. You can force it with NuGetforUnity add-on and it'll work fine with PC Mono port but the api can break on different ports.

I simply abandoned Sheets and im using Google Firebase for data transfer. It's fully supported for Unity, and so far worked fine.